# surfc: How do you make contours thicker?

Tags: matlab

I've been reading the documentation for `surfc` but can not find an option for making the contours thicker, for the contours displayed underneath the surface. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't really find any docs on this but by playing around I see that you can do it like this:

```
h = surfc(X,Y,Z);
set(h(2:end), 'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]

Looks like `h(1)` is a handle to the surface and then the rest of the elements of `h` appear to be handles to each individual contour.

Would be good to see a link to docs confirming this though if anyone finds them

**EDIT:**

@bdecaf points out below that the contours are all of the type `patch`. So you can get handles to them like this:

```
h_contours = findall(gcf,'Type','patch');
```

and then

```
set(h_contours, 'LineWidth', 2)
```

Comment: They are all of type `patch`.  To be on the safe side you could find them using: `d = findall(gcf,'Type','patch')` instead.

Comment: @bdecaf That's an interesting approach too, I will add it to the answer